# Смена родительской ветки Git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

Есть две ветки `master` и `master-old`. По сути — одна продолжает другую, но ветки совершенно не связаны:

```
A - B - C - master-old
            D - E - F - master
```

Требуется связать ветки, чтобы из `master-old` будто бы появилась ветка `master` (с некоторым ограничением):

```
A - B - C - master-old
         \- E - F - master
```

Перепробовал, кажется, множество разных вариантов `git rebase`, но получается лишь одна ветка.

Пожалуйста, подскажите команды `git`, такие, чтобы изменить историю так, как требуется.

Comment: Т. е. `master` была создана как `orphan`?

Comment: @Teivaz, честно говоря, ветки были импортированы из SVN. Да, можно сказать, что это был `orphan`, так как в коммите `D` на графике заново были добавлены все файлы — я хотел удалить коммит, а остальные привязать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @Teivaz за то, что позволил мне поверить в себя и не бояться.

Ответ:

```
git rebase --onto master-old D master
```

Наверное, это можно интерпретировать, так: к ветке `master-old` прикрепляется всё от `D` до `master`, при этом `HEAD` у `master-old` не меняется, а `master` по сути становится за ветку `master-old`.

См. также картинки с сайта `git-scm`:
[image: Начальная схема]

```
git rebase --onto master server client
```

[image: Схема после rebase]

Здесь вместо названий веток можно вставлять хэши коммитов.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы из такого репозитория

```
* commit 66d70255e22f826f927a3048d156ce4584aecfcc (HEAD -> master)
|     F
| 
* commit 901fc2f881924ca1d0f58159ea5d3013b4e2f6a8
|     E
| 
* commit c6a8666cdb4f7dc1bd0a8f9487bd7d60fc91979a
      D

* commit 02a57741d5f984450011f15aa1fe9aadb34a2efd (master-old)
|     C
| 
* commit fcd06de1c88e37624ac688eb724162624e357cac
|     B
| 
* commit 53d010f279f4d960dd7b31b9e34520321aaa8c70
      A
```

получить

```
* commit 72db07166d3ce93887e71e5b09db6548f67a4aed (HEAD -> master)
|     F
| 
* commit 9627a20c8389113d3459fad8c443c5af08c198da
|     E
| 
* commit 601073c1e8b474b8fc56afc5832eb37c022d8fb0
|     D
| 
* commit 02a57741d5f984450011f15aa1fe9aadb34a2efd (master-old)
|     C
| 
* commit fcd06de1c88e37624ac688eb724162624e357cac
|     B
| 
* commit 53d010f279f4d960dd7b31b9e34520321aaa8c70
      A
```

достаточно лишь с ветки `master` выполнить `rebase` на ветку `master-old`:

```
git checkout master
git rebase master-old
```

**Важно!** Это полностью изменит историю изменений на ветке `master`, что может привести к неприятным последствиям.

---

P.S.
Результат может выглядеть как одна ветка, но на самом деле как только на ветке `master-old` будут новые изменения структура разветвится:

```
* commit 8c0c7cb4c995ee86bd0a60324d058ecf9a3f61da (HEAD -> master-old)
|     N
|   
| * commit 72db07166d3ce93887e71e5b09db6548f67a4aed (master)
| |     F
| | 
| * commit 9627a20c8389113d3459fad8c443c5af08c198da
| |     E
| | 
| * commit 601073c1e8b474b8fc56afc5832eb37c022d8fb0
|/      D
| 
* commit 02a57741d5f984450011f15aa1fe9aadb34a2efd
|     C
| 
* commit fcd06de1c88e37624ac688eb724162624e357cac
|     B
| 
* commit 53d010f279f4d960dd7b31b9e34520321aaa8c70
      A
```

Comment: Да, мне нужно было ещё удалить первый коммит в `master`. Оставил свой вариант в ответе.